# Take Sceen Sort of Html div Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, gridview, google-visualization, pdf-generation, font-size

Hello team actually i am facing issue while taking the screen sort and saving all in PDF file of the Devexpress Gridview. I have a code that takes screen sort of the Gridview but all the columns and values fonts is big as compare to actual grid .not sure why please let me know like what to.I am also uisng some google Visualization graph in the page.

Is there any inbuilt feature available in devexpress so that we can early take the Screen sort of the whole actual page.Below are the JavaScript code. Also please check both Aspx and aspx.cs page in the attachment.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js">
</script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function CreatePDFfromHTML() {
        var HTML_Width = $(".html-content").width();
        var HTML_Height = $(".html-content").height(); 
        var top_left_margin = 15;
        var PDF_Width = HTML_Width + (top_left_margin * 2);
        var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width * 1.5) + (top_left_margin * 2);
        var canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;
        var canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;
        var totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(HTML_Height / PDF_Height) - 1;
        html2canvas($(".html-content")[0]).then(function (canvas)
        {
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);  
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin, canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);
            for (var i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++)
            {
                pdf.addPage(PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
                pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, -(PDF_Height * i) + (top_left_margin * 4), canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);        
            }
            pdf.save("Dashboard.pdf");        
        });
    }
    </script>
```